# Destructor Called Twice While No Copy Constructor or Assignment Operator Gets Callled

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    A(const A& another)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& another)
    {
        std::cout << "Assignment operator= called" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In my very complicated project, I got the following output after I started my app:

```
Constructor called
```

but when I **Ctrl+C to terminate** my app:

```
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

And in the whole process, no copy constructor or assignment operator got called.

My class `A` has dynamic memory allocation, and I have to free it in the destructor, but the destructor is called twice somehow, which is very bad.

I don't know what could cause this problem.

I googled and searched a lot.  A lot of questions about "destructor called twice" is because of the the implicit calling of the copy constructor (assignment operator).

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: Shouldn't the "assignement operator" be `operator=` or am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Since you obviously have access to source code, couldn't you simply put breakpoint in destructor and see what's going on?

Comment: Can you post a minimum compilable example where this problem shows up?

Comment: Perhaps you have some pointer cast to `A*` and then `delete`d? Also, you have misspelled `operator=(const A&)` as `operator()(const A&)`.

Comment: Can you provide snippets showing how `A` is used in your code?

Comment: @Gregg, it's very complicated for me to extract the minimum compilable example.  I understand that it's not good to ask questions like this, but it's really not easy to show an example using the class A in a very simple main function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are somehow calling the destructor twice, maybe you have two objects that think they own it through a pointer.

If you really do have two objects that think they own this one, consider using a reference counted pointer such as Boost::shared_ptr or tr1::shared_ptr to contain it. That way you don't have to worry about who calls the  destructor finally.

Aside from the debugger, you could try Valgrind (memcheck) to find where your program deletes an already freed object. It probably won't give more detail than the debugger in this case, but you ought to learn to use Valgrind (memcheck) sooner or later.

Another paranoid strategy is to make sure to set any internal pointers to NULL after you delete them.

Comment: I tried using boost::shared_ptr for my class A, and the issue disappeared.  Now I can make sure that our base code from the 3rd party definitely has some problems, because I was using their memory management classes RefCountingPointer/RefCountingObject.  The original code for the whole project is using these two classes.  Oh, Gosh...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely either your have another constructor you aren't showing, OR you're calling the destructor more than once, either explicitly or via `delete`.

A debugger or additional `cout`s will be more helpful than we can be in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Stick a breakpoint in the destructor. Then whenever it's called, you can grab a stack trace and see where it's being called from.

EDIT:

You *can* expect copy ellision to wreak havoc with trivial debugging statements like these.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the copy elision statement? It seems that if the copy is elided the corresponding destructor would have to be as well.

Comment: I tried to attach my Eclipse CDT debugger to the running process, but when I press Ctrl+C to the running process, the debugger stopped somewhere in a very deep source code (system or boost library) (it seems a thread sleep from the stack trace).  I could not even insert break points to my destructor: Breakpoint attribute problem: installation - failed.  The process just hung there.  After I terminate the debugger, and then Ctrl+C to terminate the running process, the destructor got called twice followed by a Segmentation Fault, and then quit.

Comment: If the copy constructor is removed then the destruction is also removed. The creation/destruction will **always** be balanced.

Comment: @Peter Lee: Then open a question about why your debugger doesn't work.

Comment: I finally re-created the project, and re-added to the workspace, then the (breakpoint cannot be installed) issue disappeared.  Sometimes, the Eclipse CDT is just very wonky.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using no pointers but destructor still got called twice. What I did to solve the problem is to override copy assignment operator `MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other)`. Not quite sure why auto-generated operator causes problems but appearently it does.